# How do I run the stripe SDK's Payment sheet example on the emulator after cloning the repo

Tags: swift, stripe-payments

I have cloned the Stripe-ios SDK in my machine and I want to run Payment sheet example in the emulator but upon clicking on run button I am getting an error that says "No such module found" for the line "import StripeApplePay".
Here's the link for the project:- https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios#examples
Can someone help me with this.

Comment: Running fine for me. Did you open the Stripe.xcworkspace as their Doc states? https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios/tree/master/Example/PaymentSheet%20Example

Comment: Yes I did, I tried fixing the error I stated but now the app is just in loading state and is printing that an ssl error occurred.